# How to add bind commands to config.fish?

Tags: fish

I am trying to configure a `bind` command so that it is persistant. It seems that the right file to put it in is `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

I put there

```
set fish_greeting "wazaa"
bind \n 'commandline -f accept-autosuggestion execute'
```

and I get for a new shell

```
root@srv ~# fish  
wazaa
root@srv ~#
```

The file is therefore indeed parsed but **the bind command is not taken into account**.

The same command started from the prompt works fine.

**Is there a special way of adding `bind` commands to the startup file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them into a function called `fish_user_key_bindings`, i.e.

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind \n 'commandline -f accept-autosuggestion execute'
end
```

This is because fish sets its keybindings after config.fish (in order to support emacs and vi-mode, and switching between them).

(The documentation will mention this in the next release, unfortunately it was missing before)