# How to bind Ctrl-Enter in fish?

Tags: fish

In order to [configure a user binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36336394/903011) (version 2.2.0), it must be in the `fish_user_key_bindings` function:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind \n 'commandline -f accept-autosuggestion execute'
end
```

This works fine.

I wanted to expand this binding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, by using the [appropriate modifier](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#escapes):

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind \c\n 'commandline -f accept-autosuggestion execute'
end
```

This does not work: <kbd>Enter</kbd> uses the current (up to the cursor) suggestion (which is the default) **but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as well** (as if the action with the modifier was not taken into account)

Comment: Not all terminals distinguish between enter and ctrl-enter. Which terminal app are you using?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish: I tried this both on putty/kitty and on mobaxterm

Answer (score 3):

Binding `\c\n` doesn't make any sense because `\n` is already a control character. Applying the control modifier a second time to a control character has no effect. Since `\n` is just an alias for `\cJ` what you're trying to do is the equivalent of binding to `\c\cJ`. The only way to bind [Ctrl][Enter] is to configure your terminal to send a unique sequence for that key combination.

P.S., If you grab the current git head source you can `make fish_key_reader` to build a handy program which will show you a lot of information about what different keys send (although you'll need to wait a few minutes from the time I type this because I need to merge https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/3012).

P.P.S., As of fish 2.3.0 (currently in beta testing) the tty driver no longer automatically converts the `\r` (aka `\cM`) that the enter key sends to `\n` (aka `\cJ`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following:

```sh
bind \cf accept-autosuggestion execute
```

or the following if you have vi mode installed

```sh
bind -M insert \cf accept-autosuggestion execute
```